# How do modify the height of \depedge inside dependency-block?

Tags: graphics, floats

I want to draw dependencies between words in a sentence. I am using `dependency` in order to do so. However, the edges in the 3rd and 4th level consume quite a lot of space which is why I'd like to move them down a little bit but `above` or `edge above` do not work. One does only move the label, the other does nothing.

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{dependency}
    \begin{deptext}[column sep=0.025em]
    The \& food \& was \& lousy \& - \& too \& sweet \& or \& too \& salty \& and \& the \& portions \& tiny \&. \\
    \end{deptext}
    \deproot[edge below]{4}{ROOT}
    \depedge{2}{1}{det}
    \depedge{4}{2}{nsubj}
    \depedge{4}{3}{cop}
    \depedge{7}{6}{advmod}
    \depedge{4}{7}{amod}
    \depedge{7}{8}{cc}
    \depedge{10}{9}{dep}
    \depedge{7}{10}{conj}
    \depedge[above=-10mm]{4}{11}{cc}         % Only moves the label
    \depedge{13}{12}{det}
    \depedge{14}{13}{dep}
    \depedge[edge above=-15mm]{4}{14}{conj}  % Does nothing
\end{dependency}
\end{figure}
```

which generates:

[image]

How can I modify the "height" of the edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have tikz-dependency version 1.2 or above, you can simply use `edge height`:

```
\depedge[edge height=3cm]{4}{14}{conj}
```

Otherwise, use `edge unit distance`:

```
\depedge[edge unit distance=2ex]{4}{14}{conj}
```

Reference: http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-dependency/tikz-dependency-doc.pdf